# Bounded concurrency for a TCP listener

Tags: rust, concurrency

I have a TCP listener like so:

```
pub async fn run(port: i32) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let addr = format!("127.0.0.1:{}", port);
    info!("Listening on address: {}", addr);

    let listener = TcpListener::bind(addr).await?;
    loop {
        let (socket, _) = listener.accept().await?;
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            _ = handle_connection(socket).await;
        });
    }
}
```

Let's assume `handle_connections` is an expensive IO bound operation.

I want to make is to that the server only ever has  `n` inflight `handle_connections` tasks running at a time.

What is the idiomatic way to achieve this?

My first thought was to create a [`FuturesOrder`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/struct.FuturesOrdered.html) list in the listener, which collects `handle_connection` tasks. We periodically  `collect()` on this list, running `n` tasks and clearing out those tasks from the list.

But this feels too hacky. Curious if there's a more idiomatic approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Semaphore.html) which is a concurrency primitive that can issue multiple "permits" to access the critical section. Using the one provided by tokio would look like this:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::Semaphore;

pub async fn run(port: i32) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let addr = format!("127.0.0.1:{}", port);
    info!("Listening on address: {}", addr);

    let semaphore = Arc::new(Semaphore::new(10));
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(addr).await?;
    loop {
        let (socket, _) = listener.accept().await?;
        let semaphore = semaphore.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let _permit = semaphore.acquire().await.unwrap();
            _ = handle_connection(socket).await;
        });
    }
}
```

Note that this will allow multiple connections to be `accept()`-ed and queue-up waiting to handle it. If instead you wanted to prevent accepting new connections when you are at capacity, simply acquire the permit earlier:

```
pub async fn run(port: i32) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let addr = format!("127.0.0.1:{}", port);
    info!("Listening on address: {}", addr);

    let semaphore = Arc::new(Semaphore::new(10));
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(addr).await?;
    loop {
        let permit = semaphore.clone().acquire_owned().await.unwrap();
        let (socket, _) = listener.accept().await?;
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            // force a move so the permit is only released when the task is complete
            let _permit = permit;
            _ = handle_connection(socket).await;
        });
    }
}
```